# jQuery onload screen size and screen resize

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement, resize, onload

I've got some jquery that triggers some events if the window loads at size smaller than 630px or if the screen is resized to less than 620px.

I currently have it as 2 separare if/else statements - one for onload and one for window resize - is there anyway I can merge these so I don't have duplicate the functions for each one?

Here's my code - I've had a go but can't get it to work

```
$(function () {
 var $window = $(window);
 $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($window.width() < 620) {
       $("#prd_details_smaller").append( $(".product_title"), $(".product_code"), $(".prd_reviews") );
       $("#short_desc").hide();
   }else{
       $(".col_prd_rgt").prepend( $(".product_title"), $(".product_code"), $(".prd_reviews") );
       $("#short_desc").show();    
    };
 });    
    if ($(window).width() < 620) {
       $("#prd_details_smaller").append( $(".product_title"), $(".product_code"), $(".prd_reviews") );
       $("#short_desc").hide();    
    } else {
       $(".col_prd_rgt").prepend( $(".product_title"), $(".product_code"), $(".prd_reviews") );
       $("#short_desc").show();        
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use CSS media queries for this?

Comment: I'm trying to move content placement around on the page which I can't do with media queries

Comment: `$(window).on('load resize', function () {...});` and btw your document ready handler is useless here. That's said, you should use `window.matchMedia`, not checking for window width: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by placing your code to be re-used in it's own function and calling it at the relevant points:

```
function resizeLogic() {
    if ($(window).width() < 620) {
        $("#prd_details_smaller").append('.product_title, .product_code, .prd_reviews');
        $("#short_desc").hide();
    } else {
        $(".col_prd_rgt").prepend('.product_title, .product_cod, .prd_reviews');
        $("#short_desc").show();
    };
}
resizeLogic(); // on load
$(window).resize(resizeLogic); // on window resize
```

Personally, I would use CSS media queries for this. It is still easily possible to move elements anywhere on the page using `absolute` positioning.

Comment: Thanks - this worked! I would normally use absolute positioning but it can't be done on the page I'm working on

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create one function called window_resize() and then call that function on onload and also whenever needed elsewhere.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further - I'm not quite sure what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: the comment above by atmd is basically what I was getting at. Move the common code into one function, and then call it on the onload function and also on the resize.

Answer (score 0):

in terms of merging some of the common code to make it dryer, how about

```
  $(function () {
    var $window = $(window);
    var $appendItems = $(".product_title"), $(".product_code"), $(".prd_reviews");

    function appendItems () {
        $("#prd_details_smaller").append($appendItems);
        $("#short_desc").hide(); 
    }

    function prependItems () {
        $(".col_prd_rgt").prepend($appendItems);
        $("#short_desc").show();    
    }

    function checkSize (){
        var fn = ($window.width() < 620) ? appendItems : prependItems;
        fn();
    }

    $(window).on('resize', function () {     
        checkSize();
    });  

    checkSize();
});
```